# Youtube Iframe API - getCurrentChapter Request

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am looking for a way to get the current Youtube chapter/section through an API call.
Which would work for all user cases, including: public browser extensions, embedded iframes, and videos with malformed descriptions.

1. Is there a way to get the current chapter through the **API** that I am missing?
2. What is the best way to communicate with Google and requests these API interfaces [**video.getCurrentChapter()**] and [**video.seekToNextChapter()**]?

*Example:*

```
let video = document.querySelector('.html5-video-player');

video.seekToChapterWithAnimation(0); //skips to start of the first chapter
video.getCurrentTime(); //returns 2164 (36:04)

video.getCurrentChapter(); //TypeError: video.getCurrentChapter is not a function
video.seekToNextChapter(); //TypeError: video.seekToNextChapter is not a function
```

Luckily there is a quick way to seek to a chapter with the **video.seekToChapterWithAnimation(Int)** method. However this is only helpful if you know the chapter you wish to skip to.

Youtube API offers a way to get the current time, with **video.getCurrentTime()**, but this only returns back the seconds, and not the current chapter.

### Crude workarounds:

1. Get the video description from:
   [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=%5BVIDEO_ID%5D&key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)
   and parse the responseJSON.items.snippet.description field and look for the chapter times, then compare it with the video.currentTime() to see if it is inside a chapter range.
   -- However this would not work for public browser extensions or userscripts. Also fails if the description is malformed with other or improper timestamps.

*Example:*

```
responseJSON.items.snippet.description: "Top 100 List.\n\n00:00 - Number 1\n01:28 Number 2\n03:19 Number 3"
```

2. Another technique would be to look into the description's HTML if on the Youtube site, and gather the timestamps directly.
   -- However this would not work if the video is embedded in an Iframe, or has a malformed description.

*Example:*

```
<div id="description" slot="content" class="style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer"><yt-formatted-string class="content style-scope ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer" force-default-style="" split-lines=""><span dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-formatted-string">Top 100 List

Chapters:
</span><a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/watch?v=[VIDEO_ID]&amp;t=0s" dir="auto">0:00</a><span dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-formatted-string"> Chapter 1 
</span><a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/watch?v=[VIDEO_ID]&amp;t=23s" dir="auto">0:23</a><span dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-formatted-string"> Chapter 2
</span><a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/watch?v=[VIDEO_ID]&amp;t=67s" dir="auto">1:07</a><span dir="auto" class="style-scope yt-formatted-string"> Chapter 3
</span></yt-formatted-string></div>
```

According to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support

> We support the YouTube IFrame API on Stack Overflow.
> Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-iframe-api tag.

Is there another way to properly submit an API call requests to Google?

Comment: `This would work, but this involves needing an API key, and a string parser.` = then, you can do it this way, what's the problem? - it's not clear really what's the problem and what's the way you want the solution. Please add the video sample you're using and the desired results.

Comment: The problem is you can't use a private API key for public browser extensions. The string parsing does not work with an embedded iframe, or if the description is malformed. A **getCurrentChapter()** API would work for ALL user cases: **public browser extensions/userscripts**, **embedded iframes**, and **malformed descriptions.** `Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-iframe-api tag`. The solution I am seeking is for a missed API method, or for Google to see this request, or for another method best to submit this request. This post has been updated with this information.